# How to auto refresh these randomly generated colors

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

I've tried many solutions off my head like using setInterval in various ways but I can't seem to get it working.

Currently on every refresh, the patterns will all be random.  The closest thing to what I wanted was that I made a setInterval and code but it only made 1 square continuously change its color.  I deleted it by the way.

I just want after the page loads, it will continue to flip through random colors and not just be stuck on what was already generated.

```
var rndTile = Math.floor((Math.random() * 40) + 1);
var base = 2 / 2;
var colChoices = ["#81A594","#79BEDB","#6B78B4", "#593E1A", "#99CCCC"];
var fadeTime = Math.floor((Math.random * 6000));
```

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/nL56woyy/8/

Comment: can't tell what you want to do from that question. Do you want your squares to have different color upon page load or do you want them continuously changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i can't understand your fiddle properly i am presenting my own solution here. Your first problem is that the random number is only generated once on site load. Second thing: your `var base` is always 1 and gets reseted to 0 in the `each` call. Thats why your output is always the same.

Since the code is to long to put it on stackoverflow here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ajg01y1/1/

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out around 4am last night and forgot to mark the question as solved.  Still, yours help since my solution was only in Javascript and I needed Jquery so thanks a lot.